# Removing copy by reference in CSV

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file, I am trying to replace 1st column details with 2nd column values using String.Replace in C#,This is working fine. But next when I try replacing 2nd column with 6th column values, it is affecting the 1st column values also..?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

for(int i=1;i<lines.Length;i++)
{
    if (lines[i].Split(',')[1].Contains('.'))
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(lines[i].Split(',')[0], lines[i].Split(',')[1]);
        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(lines[i].Split(',')[1], lines[i].Split(',')[6]);
    }        
}

File.WriteAllLines(file,lines);
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a code example so people can assist you. Your problem can be handled in code, but we can't direct you without more info.

Comment: `String.Replace` and columns in Excel??? That does not make much sense... Some clarification is needed. Good [MCVE] may help...

Comment: There is a miss understanding of what String replace does. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8): "_Returns a new string in which **all occurrences** of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string._"

Comment: I will also advice using something like CSV helper to read those data directly into a List<CustomObject> so you can do the math and process directly on a object and stop playing with string that need to be cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a miss understanding of what `lines[i].Replace` does. If you click on it and press F12 or F1 you will see that it's actually `String.Replace(String, String)`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8): "*Returns a new string in which **all occurrences** of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.*"

In your code you want to move values from column 2 to column 1 etc. Not remplace the all occurence of the value of column 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    // your if here.
    var columns = lines[i].Split(',');
    columns[0] = columns[1];
    columns[1] = columns[5];
    lines[i] = string.Join(",", columns);
}
```

In the following [Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uP0DPO), I removed the if and emulate fileRead and Write with simple string [] and string.